# How can I restore the default picture of a TImage?

Tags: lazarus

When I build my app, I have a pre-loaded TImage showing; the file I assigned to TImage's `Picture` property.

The user has the choice to load a different external image file with `Image.Picture.LoadFromFile`, and this works well.

But if I want to restore the pre-loaded image (the one assigned during form design), how do I do this without loading it from a separate file?

I see in the corresponding FORM.LFM file that my pre-loaded image is in

```
object Image: TImage
...
Picture.Data = { 0A544A7065674... }
```

However, `Picture.Data` does not seem to be accessible from my code.

Is there some method to load the original image (built in the EXE file) back?

I tried `Image.Picture.LoadFromLazarusResource(...)` but not sure what to put as string (tried the filename) or if this is even the right method to call.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution (a variation of which I tried successfully) was given to me on Lazarus Forum, and I repeat here for completeness:

In the Form's OnCreate event, save the current (design-time) TImage.Picture to a separate TPicture object, and then you can Assign() that back to the TImage.Picture when needed.

```
private
  OriginalPicture: TPicture;
 
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OriginalPicture := TPicture.Create;
  OriginalPicture.Assign(Image.Picture);
end;
 
procedure TMyForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OriginalPicture.Free;
end;
 
procedure TMyForm.RestoreImage;
begin
  Image.Picture.Assign(OriginalPicture);
end;
```